# Why does Visual Studio 2010 not save Environment Settings?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am changed the toolbar and window (like solution explore, properties windows etc.) arrangement settings i.e arrange as per my conventions.

Now I am close the vs2010 and next day I open the vs2010 then my setting lost and this things happen some time not always. i.e. some times saved and some times not saved.

e.g. I create macros, I create new toolbar and arrange my macro on my new toolbar and rename the display name of the macro.

Now I close vs2010 normally and reopen then I lost the my renamed macro it set the original name.

[image]

After reopen the visual studio I get this:

[image]

Comment: any one can help me please.........

Answer (score 4):

In those situations when the settings weren't saved, did you happen to run multiple instances of Visual Studio? If you start multiple Visual Studios and then close them, the Visual Studio which was closed the last will override all the setting changes made through the other instances.

If that is not the case, maybe you could try moving the configuration file to some other location in the hard drive. You can do this through Tools - Options - Environment - Import and Export Settings. [image: Visual Studio Settings]

Comment: thanks your reply.......... i will try your solution... and i never open multiple instance of visual studio...

Comment: i used your solution but problem as it is....

Comment: Step to follow to reproduce the defect.....

1.Choose Customize from the Tools menu.  
2.Choose the Commands tab.
3.Click the Toolbar radio button and select the target toolbar from the drop down list.  
4.Click the Add Command… button.
5.Select Macros in the Categories list.
6.Select the desired macro from the Commands list, and then click OK.
7.Click Modify Selection and rename the macros’ name;
8.Now close the Vs. & open the vs
9.now again follow the above step 1 to 6.
10.Now close the Vs. and open the vs
11.now my rename macro lost and get the name like Macro.ProjName.ModuleName.MacroName

Answer (score 4):

I managed to force VS to use my custom names by manually editing .vssettings file. When you add a macro to a toolbar and assign a custom name to it, there should be two entries for it in the config file:

```
<add ...>Macros.Foo.Bar</add>
```

and

```
<modify Name="Custom button name" ...>Macros.Foo.Bar</modify>
```

The modify part was missing for some of my macros. Adding them manually fixed the problem (although weirdly it didn't work the first time - restarting VS removed the modify sections and brought back the old names, which I corrected again, and then VS finally accepted them).